# Saxon-HE Integrated Extension Functions

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I should have originally posted my question by stating that our code was using an embedded saxon extension function - saxon:parse($xml)  which returned the root element/node of the xml.  However, in Saxon-HE that extension is no longer available - so I am trying to write an Integrated extension that parses an xml string into a document and returns the root element.

I am using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.6 - I am trying to write an Integrated Extension Function that returns the ROOT Node of a Document.  The function receives an xml string - creates a document and needs to return the root node to the xslt for it to then use xpath to find a specific element.  The call() method of the ExtensionFunctionCall class/types return a Sequence type  - how do I return a NodeSequence or NodeType?  How do I construct the NodeSequence from my Document?

I can step and debug and confirm the function receives the correct xml - parses this into a document, but so far I am unable to determine how to construct the NodeSequence with my RootElement.

I have other Integrated Extension Functions that return a StringValue - and those work great, but I can't glean from the class methods available how to return anything other than simple (numerica/alpha/item) types from the ExtensionFunctionCall

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us (the relevant part of) your code?

Comment: private static class SurveyParseCall extends ExtensionFunctionCall{

Comment: private static class SurveyParseCall extends ExtensionFunctionCall{
@Override
public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments)throws XPathException{
Sequence seq = arguments[0];
String xml = ((StringValue)seq.head()).getStringValue();

DocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
//the following goes in a try catch - omitting that here
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder;
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
//here I need to return  document.getDocumentElement();

Comment: Rather than posting code in comments (which do not preserve formatting) it is better to _edit_ the original question and add the code in there.  You can always edit your own posts, and will be able to edit other people's once you have accumulated some more reputation points.

Comment: The main point to note here is that if you only want to parse lexical XML to return a document tree, then using Saxon's tree implementation is up to 10 times faster than using the DOM. (The function is also available as saxon:parse() or fn:parse-xml(), but sadly not in Saxon-HE.)

Answer (score 4):

The class DocumentInfo implements Sequence, so if you return a DocumentInfo, that will satisfy the interface. You can construct a DocumentInfo using

```
context.getConfiguration().buildDocument()
```

If you want to construct your document using some external object model such as DOM or JDOM2, you will need to take the root node of that external document and wrap it in the appropriate kind of Saxon DocumentWrapper to make it into a DocumentInfo.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That works perfectly:
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(myXMLparam));
DocumentInfo docInfo = context.getConfiguration().buildDocument(source);
return docInfo;

My question is - I tried much of the day yesterday to discover how to do this from looking in the classes, to documentation - is there somehwhere in the documentation where this is described?  THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: The problem with Saxon documentation is that there is so much of it, it's very hard to find the bit you are looking for. We could certainly do with a better guid to writing integrated extension functions: I'm afraid the 9.5 version isn't even up to date. It's best to get used to finding your way around the Javadoc; or using an IDE can help a lot to tell you what the possible subclasses of a class like Sequence are.

Comment: Where is `context` coming from? I see no such thing passed to `ExtensionFunction`.

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius I suggest you ask a new question. Things change over time.

Comment: @MichaelKay OK. I've created one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899154/how-to-return-document-node-from-saxons-extension-function

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading - following this I was able to get this working with Michael Kay's help - my solution is the following:

```
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(myXMLparam));
DocumentInfo docInfo = context.getConfiguration().buildDocument(source);
return docInfo;
```