# How to return document node from Saxon's extension function?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I'm looking at [Integrated extension functions](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility/integratedfunctions) in Saxon-HE 10 (Java).

I need the function to return a `document-node()?` which is constructed from `StreamSource`.

Answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776647/saxon-he-integrated-extension-functions) mentions this code:

```
context.getConfiguration().buildDocument()
```

However `context` is not passed to `ExtensionFunction`, only `XdmValue[] arguments`.

`ExtensionFunctionDefinition` does accept `XPathContext context`, but it looks like `getConfiguration().buildDocument()` is not present in 10.

Instead, there is `context.getConfiguration().buildDocumentTree(Source source)`, but I don't know how to convert `TreeInfo` it returns to `Sequence` required by the interface signature.

Answer (score 3):

The "simple interface" (`s9api.ExtensionFunction`) does not allow an XPathContext object to be passed in. However, for this purpose you don't need the full XPath dynamic context; you only need access to the configuration object. In fact you can do everything at the s9api level without diving into Saxon internals:

```
    final Processor proc = new Processor();
    ExtensionFunction ef = new ExtensionFunction() {
          ...
          public XdmValue call(XdmValue[] arguments) throws SaxonApiException {
              Source source = ...;
              return proc.newDocumentBuilder().build(source);           
          }
      };    
    proc.registerExtensionFunction(ef);
```

If you do need more context information than this, for example if you need access to the static base URI of the expression from which your extension function is called, then you need to use the "full interface" with separate `ExtensionFunctionDefinition` and `ExtensionFunctionCall` objects.

You will then need to use lower-level Saxon interfaces such as `Sequence` and `NodeInfo`. `Configuration.buildDocumentTree()` returns a `TreeInfo`, which has a `getRootNode()` method returning a `NodeInfo`. `NodeInfo` implements `Item` which implements `Sequence`, so you can return the `NodeInfo` from your `ExtensionFunctionCall.call()` method.

Comment: Thank you. I want a separate class for the function, but I guess I can just pass the `Processor` into its constructor.